# Formula for: If $X$ is a set of $t$ elements,the number of ordered, $k$-element selections from $X$, limitless repetition allowed is

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

So I understand that if it said the number of underordered then it would have been 
$\binom{k+t-1}{t-1}$ or $\binom{k+t-1}{k}$ but the ordered part is throwing me off so I don't know what to write as this formula.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: It’s actually much easier to count the ordered $k$-element selections. These are just the ordered $k$-tuples of elements of $X$, i.e., the members of the set $X^k$. If $|X|=t$, what is $\left|X^k\right|$?

Comment: @Jaydee: And if you answer the question that I asked, you’ll have your formula.

Comment: I'm actually drawing a blank because i'm so new to this, t^k?

Comment: @Jaydee: Reduce it to basic principles. You have a bag, $X$, with $t$ slips of paper numbered from $1$ through $t$. You’re going to draw a slip from the bag, write down the number on it, and replace the slip. You’re going to do this $r$ times. When you’re done, you’ll have a string of $r$ numbers, each in the range from $1$ through $t$. There are $t$ possible first numbers in the string, so if $k=1$, there are $t$ possible strings. No matter what the first number is, there are still $t$ possible second numbers, so there are $t\cdot t=t^2$ possible strings if $k=2$. Can you finish it now?

Comment: Is there any way to message you on this? I'm still confused and it may be because I've been trying to answer this a while now. So if it was limitless alone it would be t slips to the r power . But how do i account for the ordering

Comment: @Jaydee: $t^k$ *does* account for the ordering. If you were listing *unordered* multisets, the answer would be $\binom{k+t-1}{t-1}=\binom{k+t-1}k$, as you said in your question.

Comment: @Jaydee: I’m sorry: I wrote $r$ where I meant $k$. (There was a recent similar question that used $r$.) It’s just $t^k$.